# FindRoot in Table

Tags: equation-solving, list-manipulation

I have a function `rootzb[zb, eps, b]` where I want to use `FindRoot` with it, and I will evaluate it for several values so I use `Table`. However, I cannot figure out why just changing the values `{n, 1, 4}` to `{n, 0, 5}` in `Table` produces an error related to `not a number or array of numbers`.

So first, I have this function `tinteg[z]` that is divergent at `zh`, so I put a cutoff `eps` so that `th[eps]` is finite. Now, I have this equation `b = tb[zb] - th[eps]` where `b=[0.01,0.1]` (it can be between those values; actually `b` is also a cutoff that is related to some other problem that can be put by hand, knowing a cutoff must be small, that range is just a guess, but definitely it cannot be greater than 1), I need to find `zb > zh` from that equation.

[image: Im1]

If you plot `rootzb[zb, eps, b]` then there is a root as is evident from the image below. Although what I want is `zb > zh` so I pick the right root.

```
Plot[rootzb[zb, 10^-1, 0.01], {zb, 9, 11}, AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, 18], PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.005]}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: Im2]

```
d = 3;
zh = 10;
zm = 13.128;
f[z_] := 1 - (z/zh)^(d + 1)
tinteg[z_] := -1/(f[z] Sqrt[1 - (zm^(2 d) f[z])/(z^(2 d) f[zm])])
th[eps_] := Module[{epsr = Rationalize[eps, 0]}, NIntegrate[tinteg[z], {z, 0, zh, zh + epsr}, Method -> PrincipalValue]]
tb[zb_] := Module[{zbr = Rationalize[zb, 0]}, NIntegrate[tinteg[z], {z, 0, zh, zbr}, Method -> PrincipalValue]]
rootzb[zb_, eps_, b_] := tb[zb] - th[eps] - b

Table[FindRoot[rootzb[zb, 10^-n, 0.01], {zb, 10 + 10^-n, 10 + 10^-(n + 1), 11.5}, WorkingPrecision -> 10], {n, 1, 4}] // Quiet
{{zb -> 10.10038581}, {zb -> 10.01003989}, {zb -> 10.00100214}, {zb -> 10.00010000}}

Table[FindRoot[rootzb[zb, 10^-n, 0.01], {zb, 10 + 10^-n, 10 + 10^-(n + 1), 11.5}, WorkingPrecision -> 10], {n, 0, 5}] // Quiet
FindRoot::srect: Value 10.00000000+10.00000000^(-1.000000000 n) in search specification {zb,10+10^-n,10+10^-(n+1),10.5} is not a number or array of numbers.
FindRoot::srect: Value 10.00000000+10.00000000^(-1.000000000 n) in search specification {zb,10+10^-n,10+10^-(n+1),10.5} is not a number or array of numbers.
{FindRoot[rootzb[zb, 10^-n, 0.01], {zb, 10 + 10^-n, 10 + 10^-(n + 1), 10.5}, WorkingPrecision -> 10], {zb -> 10.10038581}, {zb -> 10.01003989}, {zb -> 10.00100214}, {zb -> 10.00010000}, FindRoot[rootzb[zb, 10^-n, 0.01], {zb, 10 + 10^-n, 10 + 10^-(n + 1), 10.5}, WorkingPrecision -> 10]}
```

I want to evaluate it for more values, not just a few, say for example, `{n,0,8}`.

Comment: Using ``Quiet`` is not a good method when the code is not working. Remove it, and take a look at the messages coming from ``NIntegrate``. It has troubles integrating your function, because you are integrating very close to the singularity. Perhaps you can shortly describe what mathematical problem you are trying to solve with your code, because there might be some better way of doing it.

Comment: @Domen Please see my edit.